# Error while rewriting __repr__ 'TypeError-expected 0 arguments, got 1'

Tags: python-3.x, class, tree, repr

I have an error while debugging the following code by figuring out the usage of `__repr__`.

```
class node(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        self.children = []
    def __repr__(self, level=0):
        ret = "\t"*level+repr(self.value)+"\n"
        for child in self.children:
            ret += child.__repr__(level+1)
        return ret
    def add(self, nod):
        self.children.append(nod)
leaf_1 = [1,4,3]
leaf_2 = [2,5,3]
leaf_3 = [4,4,3]
leaf_4 = [5,5,5]
tree = parent = node(leaf_1)
parent.add(leaf_2)
parent.add(leaf_3)
parent.add(leaf_4) 
print(tree) # no error without this line
```

Whenever I put the `print(tree)`, there is an error, but if I commented this line, no error. If I change `self.children.append**(nod)**` to `self.children.append**(node(nod))**`, no error while I use `print(tree)`.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users....tree.py", line 30, in <module>
    print(tree)
  File "C:\Users....tree.py", line 9, in __repr__
    ret += child.__repr__(level+1)
TypeError: expected 0 arguments, got 1
```

Question:

1. why did I get the error? where can I see the `1` argument?
2. why it must be using the `self.children.append**(node(nod))**`? I totally do not understand the logic behind it?

I have debugged and watched values, but I can only see the variables' updates and relations, I cannot see the reasons. I much appreciate it if anyone can explain a little bit to me, thanks!

Comment: ```child.__repr__(level+1)```  should probably be ```child.__repr__(level=level+1)```  The reason being is that the ```level``` in ```__repr__(level) is an argument.  the ```level``` in ```__repr__(level=0)``` is a kwarg.

Comment: Thanks @ewong, I have modified the `ret += child.__repr__(level+1)`--> `ret += child.__repr__(level=level+1)`, but I still got an error: ` TypeError: wrapper __repr__() takes no keyword arguments`, do you know the reason? thanks!

Comment: Please update the post with the new error.  Also, I just noticed that ```nod``` would be a list object; but in your ``` ret += child.__repr__(level+1)``` ```child``` is expected to be of a 'node' type.    So once you change that ```parent.add(leaf_1)``` to ```parent.add(Node(leaf_1))```  you shouldn't have any problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my attempt at answering your question:

Your first error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users....tree.py", line 30, in <module>
    print(tree)
  File "C:\Users....tree.py", line 9, in __repr__
    ret += child.__repr__(level+1)
TypeError: expected 0 arguments, got 1
```

This is because in your class, you've defined the following:

```
def __repr__(self, level=0):
        ret = "\t"*level+repr(self.value)+"\n"
        for child in self.children:
            ret += child.__repr__(level+1)
        return ret
```

The `level=0`  represents a kwarg argument.  If you need to use that argument, you need to do the following:
`ret += child.__repr__(level=level+1)`

If you had wanted just to do `ret += child.__repr__(level+1)`, your `__repr__` definition should be:

```
def __repr__(self, level):
```

Then calling `ret += child.__repr__(level+1)` would not give an error.

Now, as for your other question on `self.children.append**(node(nod))**`;

As stated in your code,  leaf_* are lists.

```
leaf_1 = [1,4,3]
leaf_2 = [2,5,3]
leaf_3 = [4,4,3]
leaf_4 = [5,5,5]
```

Your `def add(self, nod):` method just appends the value of `nod` to the self.children list.  However, after all that appending, `self.children` would be just a list of lists, not a list of nodes which is what your expecting when you do the following:

```
        for child in self.children:
            ret += child.__repr__(level+1)
```

Since you defined the Node object's **repr** method, the above would be valid if each child were of a `Node` object; but they aren't.

This is why when you do a `self.children.append(Node(nod))`, you are actually appending instantiated objects of Node type to the `self.children` field.

So all in all, the final result should be:

```
class node(object):

    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        self.children = []

    def __repr__(self, level=0):
        ret = "\t"*level+repr(self.value)+"\n"
        for child in self.children:
            ret += child.__repr__(level=level+1)
        return ret

    def add(self, nod):
        self.children.append(nod)


leaf_1 = [1,4,3]
leaf_2 = [2,5,3]
leaf_3 = [4,4,3]
leaf_4 = [5,5,5]
tree = parent = node(leaf_1)
parent.add(node(leaf_2))
parent.add(node(leaf_3))
parent.add(node(leaf_4)) 
print(tree)
```

or you can, of course do what you did before:

```
class node(object):

    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        self.children = []

    def __repr__(self, level=0):
        ret = "\t"*level+repr(self.value)+"\n"
        for child in self.children:
            ret += child.__repr__(level=level+1)
        return ret

    def add(self, nod):
        self.children.append(node(nod))


leaf_1 = [1,4,3]
leaf_2 = [2,5,3]
leaf_3 = [4,4,3]
leaf_4 = [5,5,5]
tree = parent = node(leaf_1)
parent.add(leaf_2)
parent.add(leaf_3)
parent.add(leaf_4)
```

Comment: Thanks Wong@ewong, could you please feel free to comment on my further question here? Thanks! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67432603/two-values-are-same-and-different-after-defining-a-b-class-namevalue1-b-class