# Two values are same and different after defining a=b=class_name(value1) b=class_name(value2) in python

Tags: python, class, printing, instance, repr

In the following code, I understand that the print of `tree`(named in the code) and `parent`(named in the code) should not be the same. But I do not understand, why the `tree` is always updating according to the updating of `parent`?
(This question continues the last question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67413780/error-while-rewriting-repr-typeerror-expected-0-arguments-got-1/67427522#67427522))

Code:

```
class node(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        self.children = []
    def __repr__(self, level=0):
        ret = "\t"*level+repr(self.value)+"\n"
        for child in self.children:
            ret += child.__repr__(level+1)
        return ret
    def add(self, nod):
        self.children.append(nod)
list_0 = ['AA', 'BB', 'CC', 'DD']
tree = parent = node(list_0[0])
i=1
while i<len(list_0):
    current_node = node(list_0[i])
    parent.add(current_node)
    parent = current_node
    i+=1
print(tree)
print(parent)
```

Output:

```
'AA'
    'BB'
        'CC'
            'DD'

'DD'
```

In the code, it is obvious that the `parent` is re-initialized every time in the loop, but according to my understanding, while the `parent` is updating, the `tree` should not be updated accordingly. Because once the `parent` is re-initialized in the loop, it then does not have the same id(maybe address)  with the `tree` anymore, then the `tree` will not be changed according to the `parent`.

**Question**:

1. why the `tree` is still updating according to the `parent` even the `id(parent)` is changed every time in the loop?
2. how the `tree` is linking to the `parent` which is inside the loop? e.g.,  `node[1]`, `node[2]`.(update)

Appreciate any comment or explanation, thanks in advance!

Comment: The new `parent` is still a child of the previous `parent` so adding children to it adds "grandchildren" to the previous one. Hence, the original tree keeps growing.

Comment: Thanks @schwobaseggl, if it is as you've mentioned, i.e., 'the `parent` in the loop is a `child` of  `parent` outside the loop',  why the `print(parent)` (the last line) does not have the same result with the `print(tree)`? The `parent` in the last is the 'original `parent`' (above the loop) or the `child/grandchild`? Thanks!

Comment: A loop does not open a new scope (or namespace) in python. The `parent` binding after the loop is the one from the loop's last iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think its because your tree is always pointing to the root node, but parent is pointing to the next node.

Let's define some nomenclature:

- node[0]: First node created
- node[1]: Second node created
- ref(node[X]): Reference to the node X
- ref(node[0]) -> ref(node[1]): Reference to node 0 that has as children the node 1

Step 0

```
tree = parent = node(list_0[0])

tree is pointing to ref(node[0])

parent is pointing to ref(node[0])
```

Step 1 (inside the while loop)

```
parent = current_node

tree still pointing to ref(node[0]) -> ref(node[1])

parent is pointing to ref(node[1])
```

Step n

```
tree still pointing to ref(node[0]) -> ref(node[1]) -> .... -> ref(node[n])

parent is pointing to ref(node[n])
```

A more graphic way to explain this:

```
# Step 0
tree, parent  ->  node[0]

# Step 1
tree   ->         node[0]
                    |
parent ->         node[1]

# Step 2
tree   ->         node[0]
                    |
                  node[1]
                    |
parent ->         node[2]

# Step n
tree   ->         node[0]
                    |
                  node[1]
                    |
                   ...
                    |
parent ->         node[n]
```

A node is being added as child of another node in this line:

```
parent.add(current_node)
```

So tree is always pointing to the root element of the tree and parent is pointing to the last element of the tree. That's the reason why the ids are different!

I hope I have provided you with useful information!

Comment: Thanks@AlbertFX91, this is very clear. One more question: in the 'step 1', how does `tree still pointing to ref(node[0]) -> ref(node[1])` is implemented? why does the `ref(node[0])` can referenced to the `ref(node[1])`?

Comment: You're welcome! at the step 0 the node[0] is created without child. And the node[0] is assigned to the variables tree and parent. In the next step, a new node is added to the previous one, so node[0] has a new child node[1]. Tree still pointing to node[0] but parent is pointing to node[1]!

Comment: I've modified the answer by adding a more graphic way to explain it!

Comment: Hi thanks, I see it now, I was wondering at your 'step 1', how the `tree`(node[0]) is linked to the `node[1]`. Now I see that it is because the `parent.add(current_node)`, at this moment, the `parent` is not a new `node` (node[1]) yet. It points to the new `node` (node[1]) after the `parent = current_node`. Many thanks:)